# Why can I view my site over a 3G connection but not through my wifi?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, internet

So, I am sitting in my office with four computers on the same network and internet connection.

Two of the computers can visit this particular website.  Two of the computer get a message "Google Chrome could not find".  I have tried FF and IE also with the same problem.

I can view the site 90% of the time on two of the working computers although the site seems slow and sometimes I also get the same errors as the other two computers.

I have flushed the DNS, reset the router, tested the site on other peoples computers with success.

Is this likely to be a site issue, an ISP issue, a hosting issue?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Here is the ping from the working machine:

```
C:\Users\Jon>ping www.balihaicruises.com

Pinging www.balihaicruises.com [208.113.173.102] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 208.113.173.102: bytes=32 time=331ms TTL=47
Reply from 208.113.173.102: bytes=32 time=327ms TTL=47
Reply from 208.113.173.102: bytes=32 time=326ms TTL=47
Reply from 208.113.173.102: bytes=32 time=329ms TTL=47

Ping statistics for 208.113.173.102:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 326ms, Maximum = 331ms, Average = 328ms
```

Traceroute:

```
Tracing route to www.balihaicruises.com [208.113.173.102]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms    17 ms     3 ms  192.168.1.1
  2    42 ms    37 ms    36 ms  180.254.224.1
  3    39 ms    47 ms    40 ms  180.252.1.69
  4    36 ms   616 ms    57 ms  61.94.115.221
  5    84 ms    76 ms    80 ms  180.240.191.98
  6    73 ms    80 ms    72 ms  180.240.191.97
  7   157 ms   143 ms   116 ms  180.240.190.82
  8   115 ms   113 ms   120 ms  ae1-123.hkg11.ip4.tinet.net [183.182.80.93]
  9   331 ms   332 ms   335 ms  xe-3-2-1.was14.ip4.tinet.net [89.149.184.30]
 10   327 ms   330 ms   331 ms  internap-gw.ip4.tinet.net [77.67.69.254]
 11   437 ms   415 ms   350 ms  border10.pc2-bbnet2.wdc002.pnap.net [216.52.127.73]
 12   322 ms   823 ms   398 ms  dreamhost-2.border10.wdc002.pnap.net [216.52.125.74]
 13   328 ms   336 ms   326 ms  ip-208-113-156-4.dreamhost.com [208.113.156.4]
 14   326 ms   328 ms   336 ms  ip-208-113-156-14.dreamhost.com [208.113.156.14]    
 15   327 ms   331 ms   333 ms  apache2-udder.crisp.dreamhost.com [208.113.173.102]
```

And then for the machine that doesn't work:

```
C:\Users\Microsoft>ping www.balihaicruises.com
Ping request could not find host www.balihaicruises.com. Please check the name and try again.

C:\Users\Microsoft>tracert www.balihaicruises.com
Unable to resolve target system name www.balihaicruises.com.
```

Comment: Where is the server?

Answer (score -1):

Can you add the results/outputs of 'traceroute '  and 'ping ' commands ran from both the machines where it is working and from where it is not.  This will help in better understand the scenario. Also you question heading mentions 3G but there is nothing mentioned about it in the question description.  Can you elaborate more on that as well.

--Edit

As per the outputs mentioned in the comments also by running some basic diagnostics on the domain from services like https://www.site24x7.com/check-website-availability.html

Below are my observations -

1. The site is not able to handle load/requests. The issue can be the
   DNS or the webserver or the bandwidth of host where the webserver is
   running.
2. The DNS entries are not appropriately updated for all the regions. And hence even the DNS resolution is failing.
3. The machine from where you are not able to access, it can have some issue with DNS resolution or Internet connectivity. (This can be verified by trying to open www.google.com or www.yahoo.com)

For the first two cases you would not be able to do much except report it to the website owner. But for the 3rd case if your internet is not working we can surely help you fix it.

Comment: The 3G component was just to say that the site is working fine if I use a 3G connection through my mobile device.  The site cannot be pinged by the computers that cannto see it, although if we ping the IP address it is ok.  I will get the ping and traceroute details to you shortly. Thank you.

Comment: @Jonathan It might be a DNS issue. Try pinging 8.8.8.8 from the machine that says ... could not find host...